# Filtering dataGridView by Dates by Combo Box having Date Range

Tags: c#, winforms, date, datagridview

In my Windows Form Application I have a combo Box which has Items as "Year Range"

```
"FY JUN2013-MAY2014"
"FY JUN2014-MAY2015"
"FY JUN2015-MAY2016"
"FY JUN2016-MAY2017"
```

and I have a datagridview which is populated with customer's contracts and their contract signup date.

What i want is if "FY JUN2013-MAY2014" is selected from the combo box it should give me contracts in the dataGridView that are signed up in that particular year...so on and so forth for future date range.

dataGridView date format is "DD/MMM/YYYY" (04/Jan/2015)

Please suggest

Comment: Not sure where to begin

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 DataView DView = new DataView();
 string filter = "("your Date Row Name" >= '" + fromDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' and your Date Row Name<= '" + toDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "')";
 DView.Table = "Add your data as DataTable"//
 DView.RowFilter = filter; //Set the filter
 proceedingsGrid.DataSource = (DataTable)DView.ToTable(); //Bind the data table to the grid
```